# DXA 2.0 upgrade from 1.8 - what is bare minimum on CM?

Tags: dxa, dxa-2.0, dxa-upgrade

We have a DXA 1.8 implementation where we pared down the DXA installation, removing almost entirely the Core module, leaving only the Framework Folder, and a couple of Schemas/configuration Components from Core which are necessary for DXA to work.

We now want to upgrade to DXA 2.0, and I am guessing that if I run the installer, that it will 'install' the Core module again, with all the Schemas and Templates we painstakingly have removed. Is this correct, and if so can we use Content Porter to just upgrade the Framework Folder? Are there other steps that need to be done manually, like installing the DXA 2.0 Customer Resolver?

Comment: I have created a github issue: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/issues/24

Comment: ..and a SDL Idea: https://community.sdl.com/ideas/sdl-tridion-dx-ideas/sdl-tridion-sites-ideas/i/sdl-tridion-sites-ideas/framework-only-option-for-dxa-installupgrade

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the Core Module is not a separate package on CM-side yet. So if you use the DXA `cms-import.ps1` script to upgrade the CM items, you will get the Core Module items back.

It is possible to use Content Porter instead and exclude those items from the import. AFAIK, there is a separate PowerShell script to install the DXA resolver.

Answer (score 2):

Running Content Porter to import just the **Framework** folder works quite well, however there are are a number of dependencies on Core, which will cause 2 Component Templates to fail:

1. **Generate Data Presentation** - this is a new CT, which fails because it is linked to the Core module Article schema
2. **Generate Navigation** - this is an update to an existing CT, which fails because it is linked to the Core module Navigation Configuration schema

You can either temporarily create dummy schemas in the required location, or manually create/update the CTs in the CMS by inspecting the Content Porter zip file (look for the Component Template files 2-10247-32.xml and 2-1701-32.xml)

```
Failed items:
/webdav/100%20Master/Building%20Blocks/Framework/Developer/Templates/Generate%20Data%20Presentation.tctcmp
/webdav/100%20Master/Building%20Blocks/Framework/Developer/Templates/Generate%20Navigation.tctcmp
/webdav/100%20Master/Building%20Blocks/Modules/Core/Editor/Schemas/Article.xsd
/webdav/100%20Master/Building%20Blocks/Modules/Core/Site%20Manager/Schemas/Navigation%20Configuration.xsd
```

Comment: Indeed, Generate Data Presentation and Sitemap [Navigation] category  mandatory to republish on DXA 2.0 for core website to work otherwise we will end up with internal server error